# Spring @NumberFormat style currency for Indonesian format

Tags: spring, annotations, currency, number-formatting

i have a number that i want to format using spring (Currency Style). something like 5.000.000. but i get the wrong result: `¤5.000.000,00` and it should be `Rp. 5.000.000,00`.

is there any way i can convert it using @NumberFormat with my locale spring annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a custom annotation here. Look at below URL on how to implement it.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s06.html